# Setting images of equal size in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to insert multiple images, I think I have correctly utilized Bootstrap's Grid system but as of now, it looks very ugly due to unequal size of images as shown in the picture(s). What is it that I need to do to make pictures look attractive and distinct? Do I work on it's width and height or is there any other way that the images can be equally aligned and be of the equal size?

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="Products">
    <h1> Our Products </h1>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="download3.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Men's Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="download4.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Foot Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="download2.jpg" /> </a>
  <a href="#"> <h1> Party Dresses </h1> </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i1.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Men's Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i2.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Foot Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i3.jpg" /> </a>
  <a href="#"> <h1> Party Dresses </h1> </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i4.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Men's Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i5.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Foot Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i6.jpg" /> </a>
  <a href="#"> <h1> Party Dresses </h1> </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i7.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Men's Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i8.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#"> <h1> Foot Wear </h1> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/i9.jpg" /> </a>
  <a href="#"> <h1> Party Dresses </h1> </a>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

CSS:

```
img .img-responsive
{
     height:250px;
    width:100%;
}
.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[image: Images]

[image: Another sample[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBfKP.jpg)

Comment: remove the style you applied to the image `img .img-responsive
{
     height:250px;
    width:100%;
}` and leave boostrap handle it

Comment: and what is the purpose of the clear you added to container ... you are using V4 of boostrap and there is no more floating element

Comment: All the image are of same size?

Comment: @Wilson no they are of different size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#"> <div class='box'><img class="img-fluid" src="images/i6.jpg" /></div></a>
  <a href="#"> <h1> Party Dresses </h1> </a>
 </div>
```

just put inside a div and give the css with fixed size

```
.box{
  height:250px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The img-responsive class is no longer used in Bootstrap 4. Use the class img-fluid instead to make images respect the column width.

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

[See here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)

Comment: Yes, for now this would do it. The pictures are now atleast structured according to BS4 Grid System. However they are still not of the similiar size that I desire.

Comment: If your images have different aspect ratios they will not line up. I would suggest that you crop your images with the same width and height.